# Problems installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 7

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, live-usb

I'm attempting to install Ubuntu from a live USB, however it gives me the following error:

> error installing
>   /cdrom//pool/main/c/console-setup/console-setup-linux_1.88_all.c 
>   trying to overwrite '/etc/console-setup/compose.ISo-8859-13.inc',
>   which is also in package console-setup 1.88.

I have already tried to recreate the live USB. The system previously held a Ubuntu 12.04 installation.

Is there any way around this?

Edit:

it seems that the new installation also damaged the other partitions as I now get

```
> `error: no such device: 83327c9[long code]`
entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

when trying to restart (rather than the "Choose a boot"). However the Ubuntu installation just started with no problems.

and opening the grub rescue, is there any way to restore my Windows 7 boot as well as my old Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Please run `lsblk` from installation USB then add it's output to your question. We need to know the partition layout.

Comment: Looks like your partition table may be corrupt. Can you delete the partitions and start again?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same installation crash with the same error message.  Apparently either the the copy of the installation ISO that I downloaded or the copy created in the USB memory stick was defective.  I downloaded a fresh copy of Ubuntu 14.04, formated the memory stick and installed the new copy.  Then in the installation process, I checked the disk for errors and found none.  This time the installation proceeded to completion without problem.